# Pycharm Todo Keyword not 'registering' in modules that are in venv

Tags: pycharm

I haven't found this question asked anywhere else so I thought I'd head over to SO to ask. I am working with a project in python and have my all my files included in a venv. I noticed that the todo keyword when placed in a comment like so, `# todo mark something to do here for later`, is not working. When I create a file at the project level and don't include it in my venv, the todo keyword highlights and shows as a todo item for me. My settings under Editor > Todo are correct and have never been altered either. I am using Pycharm version 2018.3.2 Community edition.

If anyone can assist with this issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Most likely the venv folder is excluded (project tree -> right click -> mark directory as -> excluded). It is done by PyCharm by default as normally venv is not considered as a part of your project source code so there's little point in indexing it to find todo items and so on. Could you please elaborate further why did you move your sources in the venv folder?

Comment: I believe you are correct @PavelKarateev . I hadn't written anything in python in a few months and I incorrectly placed my files there.